# Pandas - check if set values in column are a subset of set values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, subset

I have a dataframe `df`, with columns that contain sets.  Here is a sample:

```
  df=pd.DataFrame([[{1,2,3,'a'},{5,'b','d',1,4}],
                   [{'z',9,'a','b',3},{'a',3,'z','b','d',9,4}]],columns=['set1','set2'])
```

I want to check for where column 'set1' is a subset of column 'set2', and return a True or False. The result in the above should be:

```
df
Out[69]: 
              set1                   set2  issubset
0     {a, 1, 2, 3}        {1, 4, 5, d, b}     False
1  {a, 3, 9, b, z}  {a, 3, 4, d, 9, b, z}      True
```

I have tried various combinations of lambdas and just can't get it to work.  For example:

```
df['issubset']=df.apply(lambda x:x.set1.issubset(x.set2))
```

Result is `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set1'`

Probably many ways to skin the cat here.  Speed is important as the real sets have 10,000's of values each, and the df is thousands of lines.  Thx

Comment: for your code you need to specify the axis with `apply` i.e `df.apply(lambda x : x['set1'].issubset(x['set2']),axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked into the performance analytics behind this approach, but your issue is the direction in which the apply runs. In order to compare set1 to set2, the apply needs to be across axis=1.

However, the apply function (like almost all others) defaults to axis=0.

When adding axis=1, I get your desired output:

```
df['issubset']=df.apply(lambda x:x.set1.issubset(x.set2), axis=1)
```

resulting in

```
              set1                   set2  issubset
0     {1, 2, 3, a}        {1, 4, 5, d, b}     False
1  {3, z, 9, a, b}  {3, 4, z, 9, a, d, b}      True
```